# Error while importing XGBOOST in jupyter nb v5,win 10, p2.7. Installed via conda mndrake

Tags: python, machine-learning, anaconda, jupyter-notebook, xgboost

Any Help regarding the same would be appreciated!

Windows 10
Jupyter version 5
Anaconda
installed mndrake xgboost

I am not able to import xgboost inside the kernel. It throws up the following error .

```
WindowsError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-afdaff4619ce> in <module>()
----> 1 import xgboost


C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\xgboost\__init__.py in <module>()
      9 import os
     10 
---> 11 from .core import DMatrix, Booster
     12 from .training import train, cv
     13 from . import rabit                   # noqa

C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\xgboost\core.py in <module>()
    110 
    111 # load the XGBoost library globally
--> 112 _LIB = _load_lib()
    113 
    114 

C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\xgboost\core.py in _load_lib()
    104     if len(lib_path) == 0:
    105         return None
--> 106     lib = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary(lib_path[0])
    107     lib.XGBGetLastError.restype = ctypes.c_char_p
    108     return lib

C:\Anaconda2\lib\ctypes\__init__.pyc in LoadLibrary(self, name)
    441 
    442     def LoadLibrary(self, name):
--> 443         return self._dlltype(name)
    444 
    445 cdll = LibraryLoader(CDLL)

C:\Anaconda2\lib\ctypes\__init__.pyc in __init__(self, name, mode, handle, use_errno, use_last_error)
    363 
    364         if handle is None:
--> 365             self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
    366         else:
    367             self._handle = handle

WindowsError: [Error 126] The specified module could not be found
```

Comment: How did you install the module ?

Answer (score 0):

create an environment variable 
XGBOOST_BUILD_DOC = 'C:\Users\xxxxxx\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\xgboost;'

```
import os    
os.environ['XGBOOST_BUILD_DOC'] = 'C:\\Users\\xxxxxx\\Anaconda2\\lib\\site-packages\\xgboost;'
```